# Ensemble LDA on different feature spaces?

Tags: distance-functions, discriminant-analysis, feature-engineering, ensemble-learning

I'm working on a classification problem where I'd like to do the following:
I have a space of features that live in $R^m$, and another set of features that are related that live in $R^n$. I want to combine the output scores of two LDA classifiers. Is this possible? What metric should I use to compute a correct classification score? What are other viable solutions to this problem, if I still want to enforce having an output that combines the classification in these two separate spaces (besides majority voting)?

I am mathematically formulating the problem like this

f-score for class 0, given an input vector $x$:

$f_0 = \mu_0^T\Sigma^{-1}x - (1/2)\mu_0^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu_0 + log(p_0)$

f-score for class 1, given an input vector $x$:

$f_1 = \mu_1^T\Sigma^{-1}x - (1/2)\mu_1^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu_1 + log(p_1)$

However recall that in one case $\{f_0^m,f_1^m\}$ have been computed with $x\in R^m$, and in another case $\{f_0^n,f_1^n\}$ will be computed with $x\in R^n$, so these LDA score computations aren't quite comparable, or am I wrong?

I wanted to have a classifier that would classify a point by doing something along the lines of:

$f_\Delta = f_0^m + f_0^n - (f_1^m + f_1^n)$

and if $f_\Delta>0 \rightarrow$  assign the points $x^m$ and $x^n$ to Class 0.Suppose $x^m$ and $x^n$ are essentially projections of a 'parent' vector $x^d$ into different vectors space where $d>m$ and $d>n$.

EDIT: I do not want feature concatenation as a solution (See comments).

Comment: Why can't you join two sets of features and have your data points leave in $\mathbb R^{(n+m)}$?

Comment: Because that is doable for two projections to two spaces. But suppose I do 30 projections and every space is 1000 dimensional. The problem becomes intractable at that point, since I would need about 300'000 training samples (~10times as much as dimensionality) , and suppose in $R^d$ I have only 10'000 training samples.

Comment: You can try to build a top level classifier that takes the two inputs as features.

Comment: @xeon You mean that the input of the top level classifier are the output scores correct?

Comment: Are $f_0$ and $f_1$ scalars? If so I would follow @xeon advice: build a top level classifier with $(f_0;f_1)$ input parameters.