# Two-classes LDA on third class

Tags: classification, factor-analysis, discriminant-analysis

I am trying to implement a $N$ classes classification with several 2-classes LDAs. I actually am using LDA as a projection method instead of classification, so it might be more a factor analysis.

If I have 3 output classes $A$, $B$ and $C$, I would generate 3 classifiers $(A;B)$, $(A;C)$ and $(B;C)$. Each generation performs a parameter selection so I have 3 sets of parameters: $P_{AB}$, $P_{AC}$ and $P_{BC}$.

When I want to classify an example, I get the classification score for each class in each classifier, sum them and pick the class with the highest score as the result class.

The score is calculated by inverting the euclidian distance $d$ to the closest point in the new space (score is $1/d$). Again, I am not sure it is the best score calculation but it seems to work good enough.

Classification of example $X$:

$(A;B)$ gives $s_A=12$, $s_B=5$

$(A;C)$ gives $s_A=10$, $s_C=7$

$(B;C)$ gives $s_B=3$, $s_C=5$

So

$S_A=12+10=22$,

$S_B=5+3=8$,

$S_C=7+5=12$

I also compute a percentage for each class:

$P_A=22/(22+8+12)=52$%

$P_B=8/42=19$%

$P_C=12/42=29$%

I am wondering if that is a correct approach, as the parameters selected for $(A;B)$ will be valid for examples of $A$ or $B$, so an example to be classified which is really from $C$ would be classified as $A$ or $B$ with a random score, which can be high and mess up the result.

I was thinking to either:

- test the example to classify for entry in each classifier, like "*are the data somewhat similar to what the classifier is based on?*",
- or maybe use all classes for the parameter selection and use those parameters for *all* classifiers, hoping the $C$ example would be "far" from $A$ and $B$

Does any of these two approach make sense?

---

I have checked [another question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/181130/ensemble-lda-on-different-feature-spaces) which seems somehow related but it unfortunately doesn't have an answer, and my math/statistics knowledge is not up to that level :/

Comment: Why can't you only compute the score for A and B when you are working in the LDA-reduced space computed with A and B? Why do you want to compute the score for C too? Having said that, it seems more reasonable to use LDA on all three classes; why do you want to use this pairwise approach?

Comment: @amoeba maybe because my "classification" technique is not working well with several classes (I have around 20-30 classes) so I was hoping on improving the result by splitting the work into several simpler classifiers. I will detail the overall score calculation to make it clearer, thank you for your patience :)

Comment: @amoeba I detailed the method. The problem can be when classifying an example which is of class $C$ (but we don't know it yet), will go through the $(A;B)$ classifier during the classification process, which doesn't make sense, as $(A;B)$ is not "tuned" for anything else than $A$ or $B$...

Comment: @amoeba, any insight?